# Is there anyway to change the color of the toolbar in notepad++?

Tags: editor, notepad++

I have tried changing the background color of toolbar in notepad++. I am not been successful so far. Frankly speaking I am not so liking the toolbar color and would like to have a dark background to the toolbar. Is there anyway I can do the same? Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try/find out in your research? I saw a number of promising results from a quick search.

Comment: @admdrew all the links point to changing the tab color etc. not the toolbar color altogether. much appreciated if you can please guide me to the link which helps me out in this.

Answer (score 2):

Proper dark mode support has been added to Notepad++ in the years since this question was asked.

- Click **Settings** in the toolbar and select **Style Configurator**. The theme you choose here affects the text color and background color.
- To make the toolbar and the rest of the interface dark, go to **Settings > Preferences > Dark Mode**.
- Here is a [video demonstration](https://youtu.be/Yk9gt--bx8Q) I found on YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/617721/is-there-a-way-to-make-notepad-application-itself-dark) on Superuser. I haven't tested it, but I think it can help.

below there's the hack (as explained in the link):

> The themes, as you guessed, can't do this (they only handle what's in
>   the text editing window). To change the colors you'll have to make
>   some very simple changes (since it's only changing color values) to
>   the source code (download from the site or GitHub).
>
> Extract the file Find the elements whose color you'd like to change,
>   and change them. All colors I've seen are denoted RGB(xx,xx,xx)
>   Rebuild (see /readmeFirst.txt once you've extracted) I've just glanced
>   at these files, but I'm definitely going to work at this a little
>   tomorrow and I don't mind giving you my results once I've solved it.
>
> Anyway, what I've seen at a glance is that you'll want to look in
>
> /PowerEditor/src/ScitillaComponent/DocTabView (I think)
>   /PowerEditor/src/WinControls/TabBar
>   /PowerEditor/src/WinControls/ToolBar That's all I noticed that might
>   be of interest so far, but again, I'll look at it more tomorrow and
>   get back to you.
>
> Edit: the official makefile will give some errors, because
>   /PowerEditor/src/Parameters.h references files incorrectly. Here are
>   the two I fixed so far:
>
> ```
> #include "TinyXml/tinyXmlA/tinyxmlA.h" (line 33)
> #include "TinyXml/tinyxml.h" (line 37)
> ```
>
> Change those lines in Parameters.h to what I've written to deal with
>   them. Don't worry about the warnings ("extra tokens after #endif") -
>   they're just comments.
>
> Edit 2: I'm using VS2012, in which the build process results in
>   numerous errors. I won't post them here unless someone eventually asks
>   about them, in which case I'm happy to do so. I should have a working
>   build up soon!
>
> Edit 3: It seems Notepad++'s provided VS project file was created with
>   an earlier version of Visual Studio, and in updating the files, Visual
>   Studio 2012 creates many problems, so if you go that route, use
>   VS2010.
>
> Edit 4: I didn't make it obvious in Edit 3, but I gave up after
>   realizing just how difficult it was going to be to get around the VS
>   errors. I imagine the code has changed significantly since I wrote
>   this answer as well; unfortunately I didn't note the version, but I'm
>   sure it was the latest available at time of writing this answer,
>   which, according to "All versions", was probably either 6.4.1 or
>   6.4.2. However, I hope this is a useful starting point for anyone else who reads (this answer has received consistent attention since
>   writing).

Comment: Please add your solution instead of just link. Link maybe broken someday. See community rules.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings> Preferences
Then select Enable dark mode.
Then you have the option to pick colors for the dark mode and can even set custom colors

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see into details of creation of the user interface elements (buttons, toolbars etc.), the answer is that **toolbar color cannot be changed until developer explicitly built such a feature into the application**. And N++ has no such a feature if you check its settings.

You can achieve changing of toolbar color by standard way: override toolbar painting routine after you grabbed N++ sources. Then compile custom Notepad++.exe which reflects your change.

If you feel toolbar coloring would be useful not only for you, but for number of users, consider [registering a feature request for Notepad++](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues) as many people (including me `:)`) already did for various features of N++.